How to get gain and offset for radiometric correction from dark and flat field images?
I'm new to the area but I was wondering how can one get the values needed to apply a radiometric correction to any image taken from the same sensor having some dark and flat field images.
From what I read the dark field is the bias value and the gain value is the flat field minus the bias. Considering that I want a value from these images that I can apply to any image taken by the sensor I am guessing I can do the mean for the gain and bias values and use them.
Also the formula I'm using to get the radiometric correction is:

Radiance = (Bias+PixelValue)/Gain

as @christoph mentioned
Is this right?

if you're asking about that library/program... take them at their word. if you're asking theoretically, that equation is backwards. it should be value = radiance * gain + bias, so radiance = (value - bias) / gain

@ChristophRackwitz yes theoretically! So the rest is correct? The bias value is for example the mean value from the dark field image and the gain value is the mean of the flat field - bias? Or am i missing some step?

are you dealing with matlab or some other language/environment? could you provide a dark field and flat field (and a "subject") image to demonstrate a solution on?

I have been spending some time on this problem the last few days and from what I can gather, calculating the radiance of a pixel looks something like this:
radiance = (DN x gain) + bias

where DN is the pixel intensity, gain is described below, and bias is the dark frame.
I pulled this conversion from Matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dn2radiance.html
According to Wikipedia for flat field you can calculate the gain by dividing the average of the flat field - dark frame by the flat field - dark frame:
m = image averaged value of (F - D)
gain = m/(F - D)

I am not an expert, this is just what I have found so far.
Some other documents to look into:
For a very in-depth look at understanding the math behind intensity mapping: https://cave.cs.columbia.edu/old/publications/pdfs/Grossberg_PAMI03.pdf
Short overview and code implementation:
https://gimoonnam.github.io/imageprocessing/Debevec_HDR/
For conversion to luminance (basically the subjective version of radiance):
https://www.atecorp.com/atecorp/media/pdfs/data-sheets/tektronix-j16_application.pdf
Please update if you find out anything else!

You’re taking the average across the field of view? Often cameras have internal correction for unevenness (so they are doing a flat field correction internally), but it is still a good idea to use your gain and offset correction to ensure a flat field. Tho see means using the average dark and bright images computed from many dark and bright images (to account for noise), but not average across the field of view.
